# What is the format 6-0-VS16-installer for?

Tags: format, xampp, installer

I am downloading XAMPP for Windows from the [official webpage](https://www.apachefriends.org) and it is downloading the installer in a weird format called `6-0-VS16-installer`.

Am I losing something or is this a problem on their side?

And what is this format supposed for? What can it do?

A descriptive screenshot:

[image: XAMPPStrangeExtension]

Comment: There are versions for Windows (.exe), Linux (.run) and OSX (.dmg) as expected and what you mention in the question is part of the name of any of those files. What EXACTLY is the problem?

Comment: @ChanganAuto take a look to the screenshot I have added to the OP. The downloaded file is not an .exe, and it is not due to hidden extensions, I have those disabled. I might just add the .exe but I wanted to know if this was the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CDN serving the file is misconfigured. Instead of the usual *application/octet-stream* MIME type (which is basically a catch-all value for anything lacking a more specific type), it is served with *application/x-msdos-application*. This in turn triggers some possibly buggy behavior in Firefox: Because a query string (`?from_af=true`) is in the URL, it somehow discards the last filename segment.

Looks like a chain of unfortunate events. Just rename the file to `something.exe` and you’re good to go.

---

The filename is

```
xampp-windows-x64-8.1.6-0-VS16-installer.exe
```

From this, we can deduce:

- It's XAMPP
- It's for Windows
- It's 64-bit (x64) software
- It's version 8.1.6
- It's the first revision of this package<sup>1</sup>
- It's built (compiled) using Visual Studio 2019 (internally version 16)
- It's an installer (as opposed to a portable version)

1: Sometimes not the software has a bug but instead it is incorrectly packaged, like a missing file or something the like. A new package revision would then be created, while the software version remains unchanged.

Comment: If hide extension for known filetypes is enabled, the .exe part is invisible. OP may just have this

Comment: Nope, I have this disabled. The thing is that the URL shows .exe BUT the downloaded file does not

Comment: I can repro this with firefox. The downloaded file is missing the `.exe` extension. Just rename it.

Comment: I filed a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1780930) about this behavior.

Comment: It appears the bug was already known. It should be fixed in Firefox 103.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't mention it, but I use Firefox. Thanks a lot for the help!